# What is the meaning of $("<p/>")?

Tags: jquery, selector

What is meaning of this line of code:

```
  myFeature.$section_nav = $('<p/>')
  .attr('id','section_nav')
  .prependTo(myFeature.$container);
```

What is jQuery selecting or creating?

Comment: Creating a new p-element. If you want to select use $('p') instead.

Comment: Thank's.I assumed that it was the solution. Please post it as Answer so I can accept answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means to create a new paragraph inside your DOM and prepend it to `myFeature.$container`.

Your code can be translated to:

```
$('<p id="section_nav"></p>').prependTo(myFeature.$container);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's creating a new < p > dom element.

Answer (score 2):

The following

```
$('<p/>')
```

as mentioned in the previous answers create a new paragraph element, the element itself is then used for the next two chained jQuery calls,

```
.attr('id','section_nav')
```

will add the id attribute to the newly created p tag, and then

```
.prependTo(myFeature.$container);
```

will prepend the p tag to the start of the $container element, whatever that may be.